# What value is returned by the call f(4,2)?

Tags: recursion

```
    //pseudocode
//n and k are nonnegative integers`
int f(int n, int k)`
    `if(k*n ==0)`
        `return 1`
    `else`
        `return f(n-1,k-1)+f(n-1,k)`
`end if`
end f
```

What I have so far is this. But how do I find the value of this function call?

```
f(3,1)                      + f(3,2)
f(2,0) +f(2,1)             f(2,1)+f(2,2)
1 f(1,0)+f(1,1)            f(1,1)+f(1,2)
         f(0,0)+f(0,1)            f(0,1)+f(0,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically the answer is just continuing what you started:

```
f(4, 2)                                                       ; ==
f(3, 1) + f(3, 2)                                             ; ==
f(2, 0) + f(2, 1) + f(2, 1) + f(2, 2)                         ; ==
1 + f(1, 0) + f(1, 1) + f(1, 0) + f(1, 1) + f(1, 1) + f(1, 2) ; ==
1 + 1 + f(0, 0) + f(0, 1) + 1 +  f(0, 0) + f(0, 1)+  f(0, 0) + 
  f(0, 1) + f(0, 1) + f(0, 2)                                 ; ==
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1                     ; ==
11
```

Comment: 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1   How did you come up with 1 eleven times? can you explain the process?

Comment: @julian Well, you replace `f(4, 2)` with `f(3, 1) + f(3, 2)` then releace each of part again and again. Every time you have one argument that is zero it will return `1` so you replace with `1` and cannot be replaced further. In the end you have a long series of `1` with pluses between them. It's pretty standard substitution. In my working out I do one expansion of each part at each line except `1` which of course cannot be expanded further.

Comment: thanks Sylwester but what exactly you count when you replace f(4,2) with f(3, 1) + f(3, 2)? Do you add 1 for each time you recursively go down the function?  I am still unclear how you get 11.

Comment: @julian No. I add 1 for each time I expand a `f(n, k)` and either `n` or `k` is zero. The base case `n*z == 0` makes it return `1` and for all the others become a sum of two simpler calls to `f` where both needs to be expanded again. You keep expanding until there is nothing more to expand. I do it step by step in this answer and the `==` is to see that this line is the same as the next.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 11.

One simple way to understand recursion function call is to expand the recursion call stack tree, which can help you clearly `see` how the whole process goes(Hope the pic is clear enough):

[image: divide and conquer process]

In the comment I mentioned `divede-and-conquer` process in a recursion process, so I updated a new image to contain the whole process. Hope this could be helpful :-)

Comment: Thanks but can you break it down for me? I know how to do the tree but how did you come up with the answer? What did you add? For example, I see in your image ( on the upper left side) a 4 and (on the upper right side) a 7. Can you explain the process here?

Comment: @julian, all right, any recursion algorithm follows `divide-and-conquer` pattern, it will `divide` the input until it reaches the `terminal condition`, then a result will be returned to its upper level of function call and be `conquerred` and returned to its upper level again until it reaches the top level to generate the final result. You already get the `divide` part, let's see the `conquer` part of left part: the lowest `f(0,0) + f(0,1)` is `1+1=2`, which is the result of  `f(1,1)`, one more upper level again, `f(2,1)` will be `f(1,0)+2=3`, and again `f(3,1) = f(2,0) + 3 = 4`.

Comment: @Julian, I updated a new picture to explain the process of how function call `walk through` the whole recursion call to get the final answer, black arrow means `call`, and pink arrow means `return`. Hope it could be helpful :-)

Comment: It couldn't be clearer, thanks for sharing. Great explanation.

Comment: Glad to help:-)